# Why is ES6 "yield" a reserved word when called in this context?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I am using node 4.1.1.  When I run this code

```
"use strict";

function *generator() {
  let numbers = [1,2,3,4,5];
  numbers.map(n => yield (n + 1));
}

for (var n of generator()) {
  console.log(n);
}
```

I get this error

```
  numbers.map(n => yield (n + 1));
                   ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected strict mode reserved word
```

If I rearrange the code to be this

```
"use strict";

function *generator() {
  let numbers = [1,2,3,4,5];
  let higherNumbers = numbers.map(n => n + 1);
  for(let i=0;i<higherNumbers.length;i++) {
    yield higherNumbers[i];
  }
}

for (var n of generator()) {
  console.log(n);
}
```

I get the expected result.

Why does the second one work, and the first fail?  And surely if a keyword is reserved, it's reserved in all contexts, not just when it's used in a arrow function?

Comment: You can only `yield` from generators, not from `map` callbacks inside them. Just like you cannot `return` from the outer function.

Comment: Try `yield* numbers.map(n => n + 1);`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It is because arrow functions are not generator functions. For example,

```
function temp() {
  yield 1;
}
```

Can we expect this to work? No. Because `temp` is not a generator function. The same is applicable to arrow functions as well.

---

FWIW, the usage of `yield` in an Arrow function is an early error as per the ECMAScript 2015 specification, as per [this section](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-arrow-function-definitions-static-semantics-early-errors),

> *ArrowFunction : ArrowParameters => ConciseBody*
>
> - It is a Syntax Error if *ArrowParameters* Contains *YieldExpression* is ***true***.
> - It is a Syntax Error if *ConciseBody* Contains *YieldExpression* is  ***true***.

Answer (score 19):

**You can do anything but not everything – Learn to delegate**

Let's first look at two examples

**1. yield**

```js
function* generator(numbers) {
  yield numbers.map(x => x + 1);
}

for (let n of generator([1,2,3])) console.log(n);
// [ 2, 3, 4 ]
```

Our `for` loop logs each value yielded by the generator. Inside our generator, we have a single `yield` call which will yield the result of the `numbers.map` call, which is a new Array. Because there is only a single yield, the only logged value is `[2,3,4]`

**2. `yield*`**

So `yield` obviously won't work in the case above. We'll have to try something else.

```js
function* generator(numbers) {
  yield* numbers.map(x => x + 1);
}

for (let n of generator([1,2,3])) console.log(n);
// 2
// 3
// 4
```

Again, our `for` loop logs each value `yield`ed by the generator. Inside our generator, we yield the same result of the `numbers.map` call, but this time we use [`yield*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield*), which yield by *delegation*.

What are we yielding then? Well, Array's have a built-in generator, [`Array.prototype[Symbol.iterator]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/%40%40iterator). So at this point, the `for` loop is essentially directly stepping thru the generator provided by the Array. Since the array has 3 values, we see 3 logged values.

---

**Watchful eyes**

So we iterate thru `numbers` once using `Array.prototype.map` but then we iterate thru the intermediate array using the `for` loop? Seems like a waste doesn't it?

Let's look back at your original code though

```
function *generator() {
  let numbers = [1,2,3,4,5];
  numbers.map(n => yield (n + 1));
}

for (var n of generator()) {
  console.log(n);
}
```

Notice that your `numbers.map` call is pretty meaningless. `Array.prototype.map` creates a new array, but your generator doesn't *do* anything with it. So *really* you're just using `map` to iterate thru the numbers, not because you actually care about the returned value of `map`

---

**Say what you mean, mean what you say**

OK, so now we know we only really care about iterating thru the numbers. So we'll use *iteration* the way JavaScript knows best

```js
function* generator(numbers) {
  for (let x of numbers)
    yield x + 1
}

for (let n of generator([1,2,3])) console.log(n);
// 2
// 3
// 4
```

Bingo. No tricky `yield*`. No double iteration. No nonsense.

Answer (score 5):

That's because the arrow function is not a generator. If I expand your arrow function, it would look something like:

```
function *generator() {      // <-- this is your generator function
  let numbers = [1,2,3,4,5];
  numbers.map(function(n){   // <-- this one isn't a generator
    yield (n + 1)            // <-- there's your yield
  }.bind(this));
}
```

Comment: Soooo picky, soooo SO.

Answer (score 1):

Just discovered you can encounter this by accidentally closing your function too early.

i.e. one too many `}`

Answer (score 0):

```
[1,2,3,4,5].map(function*(v){yield v+1;}).reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator = [...accumulator].concat([...currentValue]))
```

explanation...

```
[1,2,3,4,5].map(function*(v){yield v+1;})
```

pack all values into generator resulting

> (5) [Generator, Generator, Generator, Generator, Generator]

unpack into flat array

```
.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator = [...accumulator].concat([...currentValue]))
```

> (5) [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

for normal use

```
[1,2,3,4,5].map(function*(v){yield v+1;}).forEach(v => console.log([...v][0]))
```

> 2
>
> 3
>
> 4
>
> 5
>
> 6

[...v][0] is a bit ugly but it is works.