# Services in redux

Tags: react-redux

I'm new in react/redux, I've try to call a service cap from my sagas cap, but when I try to call the axios.get() method I get always a promime with PromiseStatus = "pending" and PromiseValue= undefined, I've try to get the promise but I don't know how can I do it.

### My Sagas.js

```
try
    {        
       let response = yield 
         StudentsService.getStudentByEmail(action.payload.studentUser)
        
        
            yield put({type: studentActionsTypes.STUDENT_DATA_SUCCESS, 
       studentResponse: response});
    }    
    catch (error)
    {
        console.log('El servicio me devolvió un error: ' + error.message);
        yield put({type: studentActionsTypes.STUDENT_DATA_ERROR});

    }
```

### My service

```
 export class StudentsService
    {    
        static getStudentByEmail(email)
        {
            
            var userT = '';
    
            const state = {
                studentF: {
                    studentId: '',
                    studentFullName: ''
                }
            };
    
            let userPromise = UsersService.getUsers();
            userPromise.then((response) =>
            {
                if(response.data.users.length >= 0)
                {
                    response.data.users.map(u =>
                    {
    
                        if(u.email == email)
                        {
                            userT = u;
                            console.log('Nombre en este objeto: ' + userT.name)
                            this.state = {
                                studentF: {
                                    studentId: userT.id,
                                    studentFullName: userT.name + ' ' + userT.lastName
                                }
                            }
                            
                        }
                    });
                }
    
            });
    
    
            return state.studentF;
        }
    }
```

I'll be grateful of your help.

Comment: I've tried to do something like this to solve my problem, but it doesn't work: 

axios.get('/api/orig')
  .then(function (response) {
    obj.origs = response.data
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem with the the answer in this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33316765/why-is-es6-yield-a-reserved-word-when-called-in-this-context)