# How to fetch data from different APIs inside one redux-saga?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga, yield

I have a React project using [redux-saga](https://redux-saga.js.org/) and I need to call 2 APIs to fetch all the data I need.

If I need to fetch all my products, I usually do this:

```js
function* fetchProducts() {
  const products = yield call(API.getProducts)
  yield put({type: "UPDATE_PRODUCTS", products})
}
```

Now imagine that my `product` object has a `brandId` field that I can use to fetch **brand** data from another API.

I wanted to:

1. Fetch all the products
2. Loop the products and, for each product, load its brand information
3. Update my `products` object to include the brand information
4. Save that new `products` object in my global state

I tried something like this:

```js
function* fetchProducts() {
  const products = yield call(API.getProducts)
  const productsWithBrand = products.map((product) => {
    const brand = yield call(API.getBrand, product.brandId)
    return {
      ...product,
      brandData: brand,
    }
  })
  yield put({type: "UPDATE_PRODUCTS", productsWithBrand})
}
```

Which gives me the error:

> Parsing error: Unexpected reserved word 'yield'

After reading [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33316765/why-is-es6-yield-a-reserved-word-when-called-in-this-context), I understood why the error is happening, but I can't figure out the proper syntax to achieve what I want.

Is there a common pattern to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is syntactically invalid to **yield** inside the function passed to `map`, since `map` has no idea about generators. A common pattern is to opt for a `for...of` loop or a regular `for` loop to perform an async operation for each item in the collection.
https://medium.com/free-code-camp/redux-saga-common-patterns-48437892e11c

```
function* fetchProducts() {
    const products = yield call(API.getProducts);
    const productsWithBrands = [];
    for (let product of products) {
        const productWithBrand = yield call(API.getBrand, product.brandId);
    
        const { error } = yield race({
            success: take(SUCCESS),
            error: take(FAILURE),
        });
        
        if(error) {
            // Implement specific error handling
            // eg: break;
        }
        productsWithBrands.push(productWithBrand);          
    }
   yield put({type: "UPDATE_PRODUCTS", productsWithBrands });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the link! I guess my only concern with this approach is the mutability that happens with `productsWithBrands` array. Not sure if its possible to always be immutable though :/